# How to input data into certain cells in excel sheet using VBA form?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm working on excel to input data to the sheet by using vba form. The excel was manually input by Data Entry Officer and i'm planning to ease the user to input it using VBA form

I have the VBA form done and it has some textboxes like company liquidity, equity and so on. My case is that I need to input the value for each textbox that already has certain format (liquidity, equity, etc)

The condition is some of the column and row in liquidity has been typed and i want to continue some missing rows that he did not typed yet. 
Let's say he typed 1 column with 50 rows but in the 2nd column, he only type up to 30 rows below. And now i want to type in the 2nd column of the 31th row.

How is that possible for user to find the desired missing cells to type?

Because my VB form only able to type the lowest 1st column by using this example code of my VB form

```
Dim lRow as long
Dim ws as Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("Summary")
lrow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlup).Offset(1,0).Row
with ws 
.cells(lRow,1).Value = Me.txtNo.Value
```

Someone recommend me to use Vlookup, but i'm still stuck with this. Any suggestion ? Thank you so much for your help

Comment: using `.End(xlUp) property` seems to be ok but you need to trigger it for the right column, for column B use `...Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp)...`

Comment: If the user doesn't want to type in the first empty cell in a column, you might want to add another control to allow them to select the specific row in that column (up to the max)